# Dual chain wifi with 2 different antennas

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, mikrotik

I have a Mikrotik router attached to a pole at a remote location. It has a cheapo eBay yagi attached to one antenna port and a regular stick antenna attached to the other. If I run a single SSID using both antenna will this cause problems? I could imagine a situation where a client can receive from both antenna but then moved far enough away to only get the yagi. Would that cause issues? I could really just turn off the stick antenna but was wondering if I could use both without issues.

As a side note I have to say it's really amazing how well the yagi works. :-)

Comment: As far as beamforming etc. goes, it's not a problem, but google for "hidden station problem".

Comment: Wouldn't that apply regardless? Are you saying this would make it worse?

Comment: Yes, a yagi (with greater directional reach) makes it worse.